# Z3: why this array theory usage returns Unsat?

Tags: python, z3

i am trying to model memory access with Array theory. i have a simple code like below (Z3 python)

```
Mem = Array('Mem', BitVecSort(32), BitVecSort(32))

F = True
tmp = BitVec('tmp', 32)
tmp3 = BitVec('tmp3', 32)
F = And(F, tmp3 == Select(Mem, tmp))
tmp4 = BitVec('tmp4', 32)
F = And(F, tmp4 == (tmp3 - 1))
F = And(F, Mem == Store(Mem, tmp, tmp4))

s = Solver()
s.add(F)
print s.check()
```

i want the 'Sat' result, but this script returns 'Unsat'.

i think this is because i read out from Mem, then write different value to it. is this really the reason i get 'Unsat'?

if so, how can i model memory access using Array theory? how to fix the above script, so it returns 'Sat'?

thanks so much.

Comment: what do you import? Or is this a totally different python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect this query to return `Sat`?

Your query comes down to asking Z3 to find values for `Mem` and `t` such that `Mem[t] = Mem[t] - 1`, which is clearly not true of any value of `Mem` and `t` you can think of; so Z3 responds `Unsat`.

If you can tell us what property you're trying to satisfy, we can help you formulate it correctly.

Comment: Levent, i am trying to emulate memory access with Array theory in Z3. you can see from the above code that what i am doing is normal memory access happening in any program: i can write to memory, then later read it out. do you have any recommendation on how to properly emulate memory access with Z3 equations? thanks so much

Comment: Keep in mind that `Store` returns a brand new array; it does *not* alter the old one you have. (This is sometimes referred to as the "functional" semantics; there are no destructive updates in this model.) So, one way to proceed is to define `Mem2` as the result of the `Store` and then assert something about the contents of `Mem` and `Mem2`. For details see: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/advanced; especially the "Arrays" section.